# Linear Regression - Large CI of categorical estimate in small sample

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, linear-model

I have used linear regression in a recent exploratory analysis.  The model explains abundance of a particular variable and has 8 explanatory variables.  I didn't indicate a primary variable of interest.

Abundance ~ Age + Race + BMI + Protein + Dairy + Fat + Sex + DiseaseStatus

Upon completing the regression, I took a look at the confidence intervals for estimates, and it has been noted by a collaborator that the confidence intervals for BMI are wide.  I've recoded BMI as categorical.

Specifically, the BMI category for Underweight is extremely wide.

**What are possible explanations for this?**

The main note I have is that this category (Underweight) only has 1-2 samples in it, whereas all other categories have 30+.  **Is it reasonable to assume that this explains the wide CI?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a lack of precision in the estimate due to the small number of underweight individuals. Recall that the formula for the 95% CI of a coefficient is: $$b_i \pm t * SE_{b_{i}} $$ where $t \approx 1.96$. As your standard error gets large, the confidence interval becomes wider. Since the $n$ for underweight individuals is 2, the standard error is likely larger than the others in the regression. The standard error of $b_i$ is weighted in part by the number of observations. The more observations, the smaller the standard error, *ceterus peribus*. Fewer observations lead to less precision in the estimate, so larger standard errors. Also, large variance in observations can lead to wider CIs, which can also occur with small samples, even if the underlying distribution is not particularly wide.